# unable Install R server on ubuntu artful (17.10), missing dependencies

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, r-server

I get the following message on ubuntu when trying to install R server, any ideas on solving this?:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
>   mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
>   using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
>   yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
>   information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  r-base : Depends:
>   r-base-core (>= 3.4.3-1artful0) but it is not going to be installed
>             Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.3-1artful0) but it is not going to be installed
>             Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, and as such unsuitable for Stack Overflow. Have you googled the error message? Which broken packages are held and what have you done to fix that?

Comment: To start programming one needs to install first. Yes googled around and decided to revert to a back up.

Comment: Indeed, and in order to have energy for coding, you need to eat; but that doesn't make cooking a programming topic.